# UiTbleview Cell Overlapping when scroll more time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I am using `UITableView` for displaying different data in the view. I am using `UITableViewCell` created by code in the .m file. Their are total 9 different kind of cell with 0 different identifiers and heights for the cell. when the same cell with two different heights in the table it start overlapping each other.

Here I am putting the code for the height of the cell method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row ==0)
    {
        return 120.0;
    }
    else{
        //For Action User follow
        if(condition)
        {
            //Checking if the Follow is shared or not
            if()
            {
                //Checking the number of Counts
                if()
                {
                    if()
                    {
                        if()
                        {
                            return  340.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return  157.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if()
                        {
                            return  340.0+200;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return  157.0+200;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if( )
                    {
                        return 340.0f;
                    }
                    else{
                        return 157.0f;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(arTemp1.count>0)
                {
                    if(arTemp1.count <4)
                    {
                        if()
                        {
                            height=height+150;
                        }
                        return  height+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if( )
                        {
                            height= height;
                        }
                        return  height;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if()
                    {
                        height= height+40;
                    }
                    return height;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  160.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  160.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 150.0f;
            }
        }
        //For Action Add New Reciepe
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  420.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  420.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 400.0f;
            }
        }
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  350.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  350.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 350.0f;
            }
        }
        //For Action Added new page
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  350.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  350.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 350.0f;
            }
        }
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  170.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  150.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 150.0f;
            }
        }
        //For Action Add Photo
        else if ()
        {
            if(arTemp1.count>0)
            {
                if(arTemp1.count <4)
                {
                    return  350.0+(arTemp1.count*50.0);
                }
                else
                {
                    return  350.0+200;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 350.0f;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Cell for row code

```
       NSString *CellIdentifier = @"a";

        UITableViewCell *a = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (a == nil)
        {
            //Follow Cell Initializing
            a = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            a.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            a.tag=a;

            //Create Cell Method
            [self aCreateCell:a atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        // Set Cell Method
        [self aSetCell:a atIndexPath:indexPath];
        [a setClipsToBounds:YES];
        return a;
```

Comment: show your code for the cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 1):

try this

First you register your cell class with tableView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

/*IF You are using class */

   [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifire"];

/* if you are using nib */

// LOAD UP THE NIB FILE FOR THE CELL
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomNibCell" bundle:nil];

// REGISTER THE NIB FOR THE CELL WITH THE TABLE
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifire"];

}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifire" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        /*

         Write code


         cell.title= @"hello";
        */
        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: It crash the app

Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116

Comment: @GauravParmar at which device and whats the version of iOS are checking?

Comment: I am checking in ios 8.2 and in iphone 5s

Comment: @Gaurav Parmar , register your cell class with table view I am  update my answer  .

Comment: do i need to register my all classes in the viewdidload ? @HushainMubarikKhan

Answer (score 0):

You are creating you cell and tagging it only when its nil, iOS reuses cell so you need to configure your cell everytime.

```
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"a";

    UITableViewCell *a = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (a == nil)
    {
        //Follow Cell Initializing
        a = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        a.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    a.tag=a;

    //Create Cell Method
    [self aCreateCell:a atIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Set Cell Method
    [self aSetCell:a atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [a setClipsToBounds:YES];
    return a;
```

Comment: but i am not using tag anywhere in the view. its just my practice to tag all the controls so. remove it also didn't make any change

Comment: @GauravParmar not the tag , you need to move your create method out of the nil, since you are not using it you can remove it too.

Comment: can you explain me why i need to remove the method outside. as this method is use for adding control to view.
1.createcell method is use for adding control to cell
2.setcell method is use for setting the value to a cell

Comment: as i said iOS reuses cell so probably, you are setting height and width of the cell in this method which needs to be reset-ted every time a cell is displayed/ created,

Comment: Yes iOS uses reuses cell so i have wrote the condition for checking the cell is nill or not. if cell is nill it will create new cell. but cell is already available in the memory then it will  not create the cell just set the value for old cell taking reference from old cell. and height would be taken is new from heightforrowatindex.